# trying to append content to DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a div to a row of content with the click of a button. My code works for the first row but not for any other row. Please help. This is the function for the button:

```
$(".addMMbtn").each(function() {
        $(this).bind("click",
            function() {
                var thisRow = $(this).closest(".txtContentRow");
                var thisTxt = thisRow.find(".txtContent");
                var cellStr = '<div class = "mmCell prep"></div>';
                $(cellStr).appendTo(thisTxt);
            }
        );
    });
```

You can see a fiddle of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/z7uuJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".addMMbtn")` will only find the elements present on the page and your code will only attach `click` event handler on them. Since you are adding the elements dynamically you should either use `delegate` or `on` (if you are using jQuery 1.7+) for `click` event to work on them too. Try this

Using `delegate`

```
  $('#default').delegate('.addMMbtn', 'click', function() {
      $('<div class = "mmCell prep"></div>')
      .appendTo($(this).closest(".txtContentRow").find(".txtContent"));
  });
```

Using `on`

```
  $('#default').on('click', '.addMMbtn', function() {
      $('<div class = "mmCell prep"></div>')
      .appendTo($(this).closest(".txtContentRow").find(".txtContent"));
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/z7uuJ/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through the elements to bind the handler:

```
$(".addMMbtn").live('click', function() {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest(".txtContentRow");
    var thisTxt = thisRow.find(".txtContent");
    var cellStr = '<div class = "mmCell prep"></div>';
    $(cellStr).appendTo(thisTxt);
});
```

Comment: Replaced with `live`, now it will :)

Comment: `live` is deprecated from 1.7, use `on()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning click event directly on the button you need to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
    $(document).on("click", ".addMMbtn", 
        function() {
            var thisRow = $(this).closest(".txtContentRow");
            var thisTxt = thisRow.find(".txtContent");
            var cellStr = '<div class = "mmCell prep"></div>';
            $(cellStr).appendTo(thisTxt);
        }
    );
```

In this case event handler will be subscribed to all newly added elements.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/z7uuJ/5/

Comment: Here the question is not for firing events for newly added elements but not firing for already existing element. But your solution is correct since it will also take care of dynamically added elements too.

Comment: OP said: My code works for the first row but not for any other row. So who said that it's not about firing events?